# Create a Beanstalk Application that only performs URL forwarding

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a website through Beanstalk that I use for work. I would like to use another website that forwards to a subdirectory of the current website.

So here's what I'd like:
x.abc.com exists. Page x.abc.com/y also exists

I want y.abc.com to forward to x.abc.com/y

I was hoping that a simple Beanstalk application could be made that would work out well. The simpler, the better. I'm open to all options though

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your setup.   Is y.abc.com an actual domain that is up and running?   What type of webserver is running on x.abc.com (apache, nginx)?     You could possibly just modify the config for the x.abc.com webserver to answer for y.abc.com and do a rewrite rule for y.abc.com to do your forwarding.